# How do I get Dreamweaver to deploy syntax highlighting for full script CFC's?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, dreamweaver

Is there a way to get Dreamweaver CS4 to use syntax highlighting when writing full script CFCs? If the document type is .cfc and they syntax is fullscript, there is no syntax highlighting; the code will be in black text...

For example, the following block of code will appear without syntax highlighting:

```
component extends="whatever" output="false" {
  public void foo() {
  }
}
```

While the tag equivalent would be highlighted normally:

```
<cfcomponent extends="whatever" output="false">
  <cffunction name="foo" returnType="void" access="public">
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you surround the code with **<cfscript></cfscript>** you'll get the highlights. I know it sucks but it is the only way for now. Wish Adobe would do something about it because I love Dreamweaver and I really dislike ColdFusion Builder.

Comment: to be honest I felt the same way in the beginning, but now I am loving ColdFusion builder for so many reasons, I doubt I will go back to Dreamweaver. I think the code highlighting was also the biggest deal breaker for me.

Answer (score 0):

When using CFC files, use this:

```
/* 
 <cfscript>
*/
```

This will trick Dreamweaver to show cfscript highlighting, without having to remove the `cfscript` tag on save.

I hope this helps some people who still have the love for Dreamweaver :)